# Gstreamer 1.0: Video from tutorials is not playing on MacOS

Tags: c, gstreamer

I am trying to compile this tutorial [Tutorial_01](http://docs.gstreamer.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=327735) on my MacOS 10.11.3 with Xcode 7.2 and not getting any video: I can hear an audio but it seems like the video window is lost somewhere.

I tried playing the same media with command line gat-launch-1.0:

```
gst-launch-1.0 -v playbin uri=http://docs.gstreamer.com/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
```

and it works just fine opening the media in OpenGL Renderer.

Any ideas?

Thanks in advance,
Max

Update: Getting this warning while in debug mode:

```
0:00:00.314802000 [336m64763[00m 0x7f93e4854a30 [32;01mFIXME  [00m [00m        videodecoder gstvideodecoder.c:1057:GstFlowReturn gst_video_decoder_drain_out(GstVideoDecoder *, gboolean):<vp8dec0>[00m Sub-class should implement drain()
```

Comment: Ok, debugging showed: ... Sub-class should implement drain()... <matroskademux0>[00m peek failed, ret = eos...

Answer (score 7):

looks like you need to run Glib event loop on mac.

Define the variable

```
GMainLoop *main_loop;
```

Then run loop after pipeline creation:

```
main_loop = g_main_loop_new (NULL, FALSE);
g_main_loop_run (main_loop);
```

Probably you need callback for controlling loop so you can use
`g_timeout_add`.

Hope it helps

**Update:**

[GStreamer Bus](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/application-development/basics/bus.html) - this link should help too

Comment: I had the same problem with GStreamer 1.15.1 and Xcode 10.1.  I could play fine from the command line invoking playbin, but Tutorial 1 produced sound and no video.  Adding the main loop code above worked for me to get video to appear when running Tutorial 1 via Xcode.  The call to g_main_loop_run() needs to come right after the pipeline state is set to playing

Answer (score 1):

I don't think `playbin2` is still a valid source plugin anymore. It's functionality has been migrated into `playbin` (I think).

But anyway - check the error codes if something is not working. They usually give a good readable error of what is wrong.

gstreamer.com Is not an official resource of the gstreamer project and focuses on the outdated 0.10 release branch. I recommend looking for examples at http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org. Even the gstreamer.com start page recommends that.

Comment: Sure, replace `playbin2` with `playbin` in your code.

Comment: You can also use `GST_DEBUG` environment variable to debug such errors. Set it to 3.

Comment: Yes, i replaced that as I showed in the gst-launch example. The problem is that it works but without video, only audio plays.

Answer (score 0):

Got the same problem when installing GStreamer from the official packages, as described [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-mac-osx.html?gi-language=c). Installing with brew solved the issue and the tutorial worked out of the box.

Not a proper solution but it worked.