# gstreamer mac os illegal operation: 4

Tags: macos, gstreamer

Compiling the Gstreamer Program works with no issues but when i try to run the output on MacOS it says "Illegal instruction: 4" and I can't figure out why this is happening.

I tried using -mmacosx-version-min=10.x 'x' being 6,7,8,9,10,11 and exported all these values as the same in the MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET environment variable. Still running this gives me an error of "Illegal instruction: 4"

gcc basic-tutorial-1.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`, also gcc basic-tutorial-1.c `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0` -mmacosx-version-min=10.6 but running ./a.out gives the same error.

Now it's supposed to play the video from "basic-tutorial-1" but it does not play that instead it just drops this error "Illegal Instruction: 4".

Answer (score 0):

Just compiling the application with that `MACOSX_DEPLOYMENT_TARGET` probably wont help you here. Most likely it is the Gstreamer library itself that has been compiled with an instruction set not available on your machine (SSE/AVX or alike). Is this via macports/brew or the official GStreamer .pkg? If none of the binary distributions support your CPU you may have to rebuild the GStreamer library yourself for your system.

Comment: This was installed via homebrew. Should I rebuild it manually from the website with the mmacosx-version-min flag?

Comment: Easier is probably trying to install the .pkg files from the official GStreamer website. You need set PKG_CONFIG_PATH for your compiler and linker to pick up these libraries though. (wherever you installed the .pc files)

Comment: I'm sorry I don't follow 

Comment: i built the tutorial 1 of gstreamer it shows Illegal Instruction:4 too, is this being solve?

Comment: As the answer says. You need a GStreamer binary that supports your machine.

Answer (score 0):

I met this problem and it turned out that the libaries installed using `brew` were not working properly. For me, I would need to install from Mac pkg files [here](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/installing/on-mac-osx.html?gi-language=c):

After installing those pkgs, mac would not link the libs automatically for you. So you would need to type the following command to set ENV `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` so that pkg-config could find the libs:

```
export PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/Library/Frameworks/GStreamer.framework/Libraries/pkgconfig:$PKG_CONFIG_PATH
```

You should be able to build with the following command afterwards:

```
gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
```

However, I found that there is something wrong with mac's video display for basic-tutorial-1. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137165/gstreamer-1-0-video-from-tutorials-is-not-playing-on-macos).