# gstreamer does not open window in very first example program

Tags: c, ubuntu, gstreamer

I am new to gstreamer and I am trying to run the very first basic official tutorial, the following codes

```
#include <gst/gst.h>

int
main (int argc, char *argv[])
{
  GstElement *pipeline;
  GstBus *bus;
  GstMessage *msg;

  /* Initialize GStreamer */
  gst_init (&argc, &argv);

  /* Build the pipeline */
  pipeline =
      gst_parse_launch
      ("playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm",
      NULL);

  /* Start playing */
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_PLAYING);

  /* Wait until error or EOS */
  bus = gst_element_get_bus (pipeline);
  msg =
      gst_bus_timed_pop_filtered (bus, GST_CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
      GST_MESSAGE_ERROR | GST_MESSAGE_EOS);

  /* Free resources */
  if (msg != NULL)
    gst_message_unref (msg);
  gst_object_unref (bus);
  gst_element_set_state (pipeline, GST_STATE_NULL);
  gst_object_unref (pipeline);
  return 0;
}
```

I have followed the installation process stated at the official site. I am using Ubuntu 20. I can hear the sound playing but as per the documentation it should have popped up a window which in my case I am not getting. Can somebody help me please.

I am using following commands to compile and run

```
gcc basic-tutorial-1.c -o basic-tutorial-1 `pkg-config --cflags --libs gstreamer-1.0`
./basic-tutorial-1
```

Even if I am issue command like following I can hear the sound but not video window opening

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri=https://www.freedesktop.org/software/gstreamer-sdk/data/media/sintel_trailer-480p.webm
```

Comment: Works for me. You may your window system misconfigured. Can you run simple x11 programs like xeyes or xev?

Comment: how do I open those ?

Comment: yes xev window opens and shows lots of logs in terminal and also it is showing black rectangle on the window.

Comment: then X11 is basically working, I don't know what else could cause the problem.

Comment: I tested the same with mac os x and it was the same like only sound but no window coming up. Then I found this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137165/gstreamer-1-0-video-from-tutorials-is-not-playing-on-macos#
Which is working in mac os x but it still does not work in Ubuntu 20

Answer (score 3):

In my case it fixed the issue - all credit for it goes to [parsley-72]: There is a bug in `gstreamer1.0-vaapi`, you can remove it and see if it helps you (in my case, it fixed the issue):

```
sudo apt-get remove gstreamer1.0-vaapi
```

On [this page](https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/gstreamer-vaapi/+bug/1849735) you can find information about the bug