# GStreamer Tutorial 1 - hear sound but no video

Tags: gstreamer

I'm continuing my journey through GStreamer and am stuck once again. I'm running the first tutorial and can hear sound but no video.

The error that I'm seeing is:

```
gldisplay gstgldisplay_cocoa.m:175:gst_gl_display_cocoa_setup_nsapp: Custom NSApp initialization failed
```

Am I missing a plugin or some required library here? I'm on an M1 Mac.

I should note, that via the command line everything works just fine.

```
gst-launch-1.0 playbin uri="file:///Users/vukasin/Downloads/sintel_trailer-480p.webm"
```

Maybe this is OpenGL related? I'm guessing its trying, and failing to open the video.

Comment: This was the solution: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35137165/gstreamer-1-0-video-from-tutorials-is-not-playing-on-macos

Answer (score 1):

I just figured out what was going on with this error after spending hours thinking my system was not setup correctly. This issue is that a GMainLoop must be ran for the windowing to work correctly from the main thread. Interesting enough the tutorial 12 does it correctly and does the same exact thing. https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/streaming.html?gi-language=c